# Blazor: StateHasChanged could be called in parent or if called in Child has better performance?

Tags: blazor, rendering, rerender

My question is regarding StateHasChanged:

I have this code in Parent:

```
    [Inject]
    private IProjectActionsService ProjectActionsService { get; set; }
    private ProjectModel Project { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()        
    {                                 
        ProjectActionsService.FavouritesOnChange += FavouriteTasksChanged;

        await GetProjectData(Project);
    }

    private void FavouriteTasksChanged(TreeItemModel treeItem)
    {
        var remove = treeItem.Hidden;

        Project.TreeDataDict.TryGetValue(treeItem.NodeId, out treeItem);

        if (remove)
        {
            Project.TreeDataSource[0].Children.Remove(treeItem);
        }
        else
        {
            Project.TreeDataSource[0].Children.Add(treeItem);
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

this rerenders the child which show the favourites to the user

Here is Child:

```
    [Parameter]
    public ProjectModel Project { get; set; }
```

My question is if instead calling StateHasChanged in Parent, I could do the following to child:

```
    [Parameter]
    public ProjectModel Project { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()        
    {                                 
        ProjectActionsService.FavouritesOnChange += FavouriteTasksChanged;
    }

    private void FavouriteTasksChanged(TreeItemModel treeItem)
    {
        var remove = treeItem.Hidden;

        Project.TreeDataDict.TryGetValue(treeItem.NodeId, out treeItem);

        if (remove)
        {
            Project.TreeDataSource[0].Children.Remove(treeItem);
        }
        else
        {
            Project.TreeDataSource[0].Children.Add(treeItem);
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

And call StatesHasChanged on child.

Will this have any impact on performance (ex: not making parent rerender) or will do exactly the same (ex: just render where is being shown to the user which happens only in the child) ??

Update starts Here:

So I did some tests and for fact using StatHasChanged in Parent will call OnAfterRender of every child Component. By running in the child it only runs its own OnAfterRender.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this have any impact on performance (ex: not making parent rerender)

Yes. Call StateHasChanged for the smallest scope necessary.
Assuming the Tree is rendered in the Child Component.

> what I have read tells me that only the changed properties will be rendered

That is correct but first the 'diffing engine' has to run, taking time.  And that engine errs on the safe side: any Component with a mutable object as parameter will be re-rendered.

From the [Blazor performance page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly):

> 3. After a new set of parameter values is received, each component decides whether to rerender. By default, components rerender if the parameter values may have changed, for example, if they're mutable objects.

---

On a side note, what is the lifetime (scope) of the ProjectActionsService? I think you had better have  `@implement IDisposable` and use that to unsubscribe (`-=`) your eventhandlers.

Comment: Can you point any documentation that refers that about StateHasChanged? Because so far what I have read tells me that only the changed properties will be rendered meaning that it makes  no diferent where you call StateHasChanged but it is not in any official documentation and I cant find it.. About the side note I have IDisposable in my code, here I putted just a small example

Answer (score 1):

I'll add some more general information to the answers above.

1. Using a Service to manage your data is good, as is using an event to notify changes.  Any component that needs to know about a change to the data it's using registers for the notification and reacts to any changes - usually by re-rendering.  Trying to force re-rendering of a child from a parent is a no-no.
2. You should only have one version of the truth - in you case `ProjectModel`.  It's not clear from your code if `Project` is just a reference to `Project` in your data service, or a local copy which you are manipulating in say `Project.TreeDataSource[0].Children.Remove(treeItem);`.  Make sure your data, and all data manipulation, is in the service and, either refer directly to `Project` in the service or a local reference to it.  The principle of "Separation of Concerns".

You don't show us your rendering code, so it's hard to comment on what `StateHasChanged` will re-render whenever it's called after you change `TreeDataSource`.  In general when a re-render takes place, only the changes get communicated to the browser window.  However, removing elements from a displayed list can cause a fairly major re-render.  You can use the @key to help the renderer reduce the load.